# sql statement with an if inside of it?

Tags: sql

I've got the following sql query which works. However I need help with the fields that have a /10000 calculation. Occasionally there will be no data in the field to be calculated, so my query below is returning a 0. How do I check for data > 0 before I perform the /10000 calculation?

```
SELECT
timesheet.customerID,
customer.customer,
timesheet.projectID,
project.project_title,
timesheet.chargeID,
charge.charge_description,
timesheet.notes,
timesheet.mon/10000,
timesheet.tues/10000,
timesheet.wed/10000,
timesheet.thurs/10000,
timesheet.fri/10000,
timesheet.sat/10000,
timesheet.sun/10000,
timesheet.lineID

FROM
timesheet_line timesheet
LEFT JOIN customer ON timesheet.customerID = customer.customerID
LEFT JOIN project ON timesheet.projectID = project.projectID
LEFT JOIN charge_rate charge ON timesheet.chargeID = charge.chargeID

WHERE
timesheet.timesheetID = '" & tTimesheetID & "' --VBA variable added here

ORDER BY
timesheet.lineID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this (example column)

```
CASE timesheet.wed > 0 THEN timesheet.wed/10000 ELSE null END as wed,
```

if the value can be null then you have to do this:

```
CASE COALESCE(timesheet.wed,0) > 0 THEN timesheet.wed/10000 ELSE null END as wed,
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

- The `COALESCE` function is perfect when you want to translate possible `NULL` values to something else:

  ```
  COALESCE(NullableColumn / 10000, DefaultValueIfNull)
  -- btw., NULL divided by 10,000 should yield NULL, not 0.
  ```
- Some SQL dialects (such as SQL Server's T-SQL) have a very similar function called `ISNULL`.
- `CASE` is closer to an `if`:

  ```
  CASE WHEN NullableColumn IS NOT NULL THEN NullableColumn / 1000 ELSE DefaultValue END
  ```